# Exchange short-lived access token for long-lived, not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, access-token

I am trying to exchange a short-lived user access token for a ling-lived, but getting an an error (in all.js):

ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

...TZCOZCkuZBxZAzVUSokiOJbXZAHhESJvuA97qXTpVbVj3P7AZDZD&expires=512326

response.error.message: unknown error

Code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
           FB.init({
               appId: 'xxx', // App ID
               status: true, // check login status
               cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
               xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
               oauth: true
           });

           FB.login(function (response) {
                    if (response) {

                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                        if (response.status === 'connected') {

                            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                            var OauthParams = {};
                            OauthParams['client_id'] = 'xxx';
                            OauthParams['client_secret'] = 'xxx';
                            OauthParams['grant_type'] = 'fb_exchange_token';
                            OauthParams['fb_exchange_token'] = accessToken;
                            OauthParams['response_type'] = 'token';
                            console.log(accessToken);

                            FB.api('/oauth/access_token', 'post', OauthParams, function(response) {
                                if (!response || response.error) {
                                    console.log(response.error.message);
                                } 
                                else {
                                    console.log(response.accesstoken);
                                }
                            });        
                        }
                    });
                    };

           }, { scope: 'manage_pages' });

       };


}

(function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks,
/M

Answer (score 1):

according to scenario 4 of the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) you have to send a `GET` request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

maybe the problem is that you are using `POST` request, but I am not sure

P.S. I wouldn't recommend to use APP_SECRET on client side

Comment: GET request didn't change the FB error message and Firebug error. This client code is just for test purpose, of course I will not reveal the APP Secret later on.

Comment: That means you will not do it _client-side_ later on anyways – so why are you “testing” something that will never be used?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue running tests from a FB Javascript SDK client. The problem on my end was that SDK was tripping handling the access_token in `fb_exchange_token`. Changing just last three characters in this access token string made the error go away. Of course, this doesn't help solving the problem, but at least this is where the issue was in my case.

Since these calls must be made from a server anyway, I am not going to proceed troubleshooting this further.